# Rendering React objects dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components, rendering

My question is just about idea and creativity of you.

I have react component that is getting information from SQL database:

```
const [offers,setOffers] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8085/incoming`)
    .then(res=>{
       setOffers(res.data.recordset)

   })
   .catch(error=>console.log(error))},[])
```

just when page is loaded.

In JSX I put one function that is filling my table:

```
<tbody className="table-hover">
            {OfferItem(offers)}
        </tbody>
```

The function is:

```
const OfferItem = (array)=>{
if(array!==undefined){
    return array.map((item,index)=>{
        return <IncomingOffer  singleitem={item} index={index+1} key={item.Number}/>
    })
}}
```

So far so good but I want to have input field that is providing dynamic search and re-rendering. So I put:

```
            <label>Относно:</label><input onChange={searchAbout} />
```

And created my function:

```
const searchAbout = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault(e)
    const string = e.target.value.toUpperCase()
    const res = offers.filter(el=>Object.values(el).some(val=>val.toUpperCase().includes(string)))
    setOffers(res)
}
```

In the way it is wrote it is working when typing in input field but as you see it is completely filtering the array and I am loosing all other items in it. So I was wondering for a way that I am filtering and re-rendering items but for example when I use backspace or remove the whole search criteria to see again my whole array information. **I must admit I know how my code is working** and what is expected but I do not know how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: How about a separate state variable that stores the filtered version of the offers? So if the input changes you can re-filter from the full offers and set the result in your new state var.

Comment: Can't because in my JSX I am passing offers as argument to my function

Comment: Looks like it depends on the desired behavior.
The simplest fix is to check for empty filter input in searchAbout(). I.e. if (string.length === 0) setOffers(offers);

Comment: Honestly, you are completely right! I did it in your way @ApplePearPerson